# How to insert data to an ordered, random accessible list without re-index/moving items after insertion point?

Tags: c++, algorithm, qt, data-structures, insert

I am developing a Qt custom widget which can show all files in given folders. Everything is OK except the speed.

The widget can show items in the following order:

1. All files are arranged into 4 groups: Image, Audio, Video and Other.
2. All files in each group are sorted by extension name and base name.

In addition, the widget is random accessible. User can scroll to anywhere to show correspondent item. User can also hide or show any group of items.

The internal data structure of the widget is:

1. 4 global ordered deques for above groups.
2. The traversal thread inserts new item to 4 ordered local deques. (Use binary search to locate insert point)
3. If local deque is full, dump them into global deque. (Use merge sort) This can reduce the exclusive access frequency of global deques.

The performance is good at start. However it become slower and slower when data getting large (The threshold is about 100,000). After investigating the code I found the root cause is re-indexing and data movement of deque.

Basically deque is an array or pointer. To keep the index it have to move pointers after insertion point forward after insertion (re-indexing). If data size is big, this action takes too much time and becomes to the bottleneck of performance.

I tried set and map. Neither of them is good replacement of deque or vector. Set cannot be accessed through a simple numeric index (It is indexed by hash of item) and map is sorted by index.

I need a structure which satisfies:

1. Provides an ordered (By contents of item) list.
2. Can be accessed through a simple, increasing, numeric index.
3. **Insertion is very fast.**

Can anyone help me?

Comment: A [skip list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list) provides O(log n) insertion and lookup by key, but O(n) lookup by index. Which *might* be fast enough for your needs. But if you want O(log n) indexed lookup, you can create an indexable skip list. The required modifications are in the linked article. A quick search of "skip list C++" reveals several implementations that you might be able to use.

Comment: OK, I will try skip list. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

What about use a tree.

In fact, I think QList is good enough.

In your UI widget, you don't need to set up all the file widgets once, just set up the ones that will be showed. Like a virtual list.

Try Qt's Model View, use a model to hold the real data that is ordered, and just set up the view items that need to be show.

Comment: Tree is easy to insert indeed. But re-indexing is needed after every insertion...   I had tried model-view of qt. But the problem is still there. The internal data structure is continuly updated by worker thread. When the number of file grows large, every insertion takes much time.